# Flutter Voice recording custom waveform

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation, voice-recognition, waveform

I am trying to build a **voice assistant application** using **Flutter**, I want to make a **sound wave** like the -> [Wave image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIQvI.png)
of course, I have made this widget using animations ! :

```
  Center(
   child: Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
       ...List<Widget>.generate(12, (index) => VoiceLine())
     ],
   ),
 ),
```

**VoiceLine widget :**  build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  width: 8.0,
  height: 8.0 + _animation.value,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: AppColors.secondaryColorWhite,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
);
```

But I want this wave [ size of each line ] to be sensitive to the **user's voice** 

 *How can I do this?*

Answer (score 0):

If you feel ok using a 3rd party package to achieve this, you can use either:

- Audio Waveforms - https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms
- Audio Visualizer - https://pub.dev/packages/audio_visualizer

You may take an eye of them and check if they can fulfill your needs.